# What is a page author

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

While reading Java Platform Enterprise Edition tutorial, I came across two phrases: "page authors" and "application developers".

I understand what they mean by "application developers", but I don't get what do they mean when they say "page author"?

For instance, here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-page-core002.htm

Comment: Would be my guess, too. It's not an established thing/role/position in the world of software development at least (from what I know)

Comment: Maybe a person who developed that particular JSP?

Comment: @khelwood I believe the same but I think there should be some explanation because everything is well defined in our world.

Comment: @khelwood So there is no standard definition for it huh?

Comment: @khelwood Even I did not wanted to ask such a silly question but it is used so frequently in the tutorial that I thought I should just confirm weather it has some meaning associated.

Comment: Please share link of that tutorial.

Comment: Could you link the specific page? A quick skim through the tutorial did not yield results.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-page-core002.htm

Comment: In that case it's really just "the person writing the page"

Comment: With page being defined as such: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnarb.html

Comment: "Page authors" refers to the developers who usually design static-content pages (like HTML pages) and have no experience in developing dynamically-changing pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Page author* just refers to a specific development role:

> **Page author**, who creates pages by using the JavaServer Faces tag
>   libraries.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnapl.html